# Run background task with console application from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, .net-3.5, background-task

My requirement is to send emails within the web application from an external server that takes around 4 to 5 seconds on average to process and send the confirmation email. I do not want the user to wait for this, so i trigger a console application with Process().StartInfo.Start() and it does it in background. The question is how much i can rely on this as during normal days the application sends around 10 thousand emails daily and in high traffic days it may surpass 80 thousand. What possible issues/problems the application or server may run into? Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: which .NET version do you use?

Comment: you can try [Task Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Maximilian for the response. The application is using .Net framework 3.5

Comment: sadly `Task` was published with `.NET 4`.
but you can try to open a thread instead of triggering a console application.

Comment: We do have the options either we can use Thread-pool or custom threads but both of these solutions have their own limitation. If number of background tasks exceed a certain number it may exhaust the application and in few cases may take down the application pool. Also the Thread pools typically have a maximum number of threads. If all the threads are busy, additional tasks are put in queue until they can be serviced as threads become available.

Comment: okay I see your point

Answer (score 1):

You can use following method to achieve this:

1. Create a `.aspx` page  and write you business code here (e.g. email
   send)
2. Where required, call this page using Javascript along with parameters in querystring. You can create an image element and set its source to that page.

   ```
   var img = new Image();
   img.scr = "perform-operation.aspx?[parametervalues]";
   ```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Console application has drawback, if you plan to invoke console application for each email separately, any new process takes long to load and clean up, this is too much overhead on cpu. Instead, the best alternative is to host another website in IIS, this new website will have its own Application Pool, which will create and host process. IIS will shutdown the process if no request is served. You can setup Web Farm by running more worker process per application.

Other alternative is to run console or windows service all the time, let it be in the memory but has a web service host listening for email requests, if a request is received from your web application, this background service will send email on new thread and go back on waiting state. Basically it is a self hosted WCF service. This is quite same as hosting another website on IIS.

I prefer IIS based hosting as it is easy to setup, does not require any extra permissions and in future, to scale horizontally, you can easily move this mail service to other server.

Comment: Having said that the emails should be sent in background, How this newly hosted website will communicate with the original application in real time? Same is with Background service how the web service will be listening to the events inside web application? perhaps from the DB?

Comment: Newly created service will be hosting a web service, a kind of rest service, your asp.net application should call as http://myotherapp.domain.com/sendemail?.... , by using WebClient or HttpClient.

Comment: In this case it will have to wait till the execution is complete.

Comment: No, you can create a new asynchronous task in your web service app, and you can return back, however by doing this, a new task is created but not inside your own application pool. The idea is to separate mail sending logic in separate web service app.

Comment: This can be helpful when we have multiple tasks running and we call them asynchronously and they will work independently, but here in this case we have a single time consuming task and the page will not load unless the task is finished.